# Searching a calender for a date on a specific day

Tags: date, excel, vba

I need a user to input closing stock and date, then take closing stock and subtract it from forecast sales (via lookup on set values, dependent on week and day), then add 6 days to the input date, if the output date isn't a Monday, Wednesday or Friday then it must output the previous closest Monday, Wednesday or Friday(whichever is first).

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I don't know how to do this yet, or whether it can be done. I was supposed to use excel formulas but it cant be done that way so now i'm stumped.

Comment: I'll bet it can be done via formulas - it might take a couple of intermediary columns to make the formulas easier & more readable, but it sounds possible. Post what you've got so far, and you're more likely to get some help moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the image below what you want?

You will want to place the Add table in a hidden worksheet or on the far right of the worksheet.  The formula in D2, which was copied down the column, is:

`=B2+VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(B2),$F$2:$G$8,2,TRUE)`

**Edit** Having Reread this answer, I think a little more explanation is required.  `WEEKDAY` converts a date into a day of the week as a number between 1 and 7.  These numbers are in column 1 of the Add table.  The second column is the number of days to be added to the date to advance to the required Monday, Wednesday or Friday.  `VLOOKUP` looks up the week day number and find the number of days to add.

[image: Image showing result of formula]

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much. I never thought of it that way.

Comment: @Retsol  You are welcome.  The advantage of being old is that over the years you have seen and tried everything.  I would be grateful if you accepted the answer.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. i clicked the green tick, i think it's accepted. Thank you once again